# Change the attribute of an input button using .withSuccessHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, google-apps-script

I'm trying to build a user interface in Google Apps Script using HTML Service.  I'd like my button to change from "Save" to "SAVED!" when the data is successfully saved to the user's script properties.  I know the function saveProperties is executing successfully because the user properties are being updated.  Not sure why what I'm doing is not working. The button still says "Save".

script file

```
function saveProperties(first, last, email) {  
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('first', first);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('last', last);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('email', email);
  return;
}
```

html file

```
<input type="text" id="first"/>
<input type="text" id="last"/>
<input type="text" id="email"/>
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Save"/>

<script>
function onSubmit(){
    var $first = $('#first').val();
    var $last = $('#last').val();
    var $email = $('#email').val();
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(changeButton)
    .saveProperties($first, $last, $email);
}

function changeButton(test){
    $('#submitButton').attr('value','SAVED!');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My test does not include external libraries such as jQuery, but should have no difference.

**Code.gs**

```js
function saveProperties(first, last, email) {  
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('first', first);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('last', last);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('email', email);
  return;
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

**JavaScript.html**

```html
<script>
function onSubmit(obj) {
    var $first = document.getElementById('first').value;
    var $last = document.getElementById('last').value;
    var $email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(changeButton).withUserObject(obj).saveProperties($first, $last, $email);
}

function changeButton(value, obj) {
    obj.value = 'SAVED!';
}
</script>
```

**Test.html**

```html
<input type='text' id='first'/>
<input type='text' id='last'/>
<input type='text' id='email'/>
<input id='submitButton' name='submitButton' type='button' value='Save' onclick='onSubmit(this)' />
<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
```

**UPDATE - Alternative version:**

**JavaScript.html**

```html
<script>
function onSubmit() {
    var $first = document.getElementById('first').value;
    var $last = document.getElementById('last').value;
    var $email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(changeButton).saveProperties($first, $last, $email);
}

function changeButton() {
    document.getElementById('submitButton').value = 'SAVED!';
}
</script>
```

**Test.html**

```html
<input type='text' id='first'/>
<input type='text' id='last'/>
<input type='text' id='email'/>
<input id='submitButton' name='submitButton' type='button' value='Save' onclick='onSubmit()' />
<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
```